# Angular theming based on URL

Tags: angular, sass, themes

I'm looking for a solution where you have 1 angular project with multiple themes. Based on the URL a specif theme is loaded (style, images, etc). All the components will be the same in all themes.

**For example:** 
URL A: loads style-a.scss and image-a.png 
URL B: loads style-b.scss and image-b.png

When there is no theme specif image or style the defaults get loaded. In a perfect world, there is also an option to build a specif theme, so you don't have files from other themes.

I've already tried making a script and check for the web URL, and then load the specif theme styles. The problem is, this can't create a default fallback. Because there will always be a URL. Also sometimes the site is loaded faster than the function is completed, and the site 'flashes' from styling.

Answer (score 1):

This is something similar to what you want.

https://juristr.com/blog/2019/08/dynamically-load-css-angular-cli/

For URL thing you could could check the environment at the time of bootstrap and load the style accordingly.

Comment: Could you give an example of checking the enviroment at the time of bootstrap? The article you linked is great.

Comment: That depends on how your application is structured. Option 1 :  If you have something like /user call where you get client details like name logo etc, you can use that, Option 2 : Check the URL and then decide, Option 3: You can also use build configurations and generate multiple builds for different clients using same source code.